# Kafka consumer wouldn't consume

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have a service with consumer where it stops consuming messages until service is restarted. I am new to Kafka. Can someone tell me possible failure areas to look? There are no errors in service logs.

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Most likely the consumer thread is "stuck" somewhere in your code; take a thread dump to see what the thread is doing.